# Injected HttpClient ignores IHttpClientFactory configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I've created a custom library which automatically sets up Polly policies for specific services which depend on `HttpClient`.

This is done using the `IServiceCollection` extension methods and the typed client approach. A simplified example:

```cs
public static IHttpClientBuilder SetUpFooServiceHttpClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    return services
            .AddHttpClient<FooService>()
            .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
}
```

The example service:

```cs
public class FooService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    // OPTION 1
    public FooService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _client = httpClient;
    }

    // OPTION 2
    public FooService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(GetType().Name);
    }

    public void DoJob()
    {
         var test = _client.GetAsync("http://example.com");
    }
}
```

Fetching the service from the DI container (this is from a test project):

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.SetUpFooServiceHttpClient();
        
services.AddSingleton<FooService>();

var fooService = services
                   .BuildServiceProvider()
                   .GetRequiredService<FooService>();

// Perform test
fooService.DoJob();
```

*Note: In this test project, I also add an extra mocked handler since I'm trying to mock http status responses, but the mocked handler being present or not is identical to the Polly policy being present or not, so I omitted the mocked handler from the example code.*

Notice the two different constructors in `FooService`. Depending on which one I comment out and which one I leave in, I get different outcomes. All other code remains untouched.

- Option 1, injecting the `HttpClient` directly, ignores all my configuration. I get a standard http client with no Polly policy handler.
- Options 2, injecting the `IHttpClientFactory` and requesting the client using the current type name (i.e. `FooService`) respect my configuration. I get a custom http client which contains the Polly policy handler (and any other handlers I may have configured, e.g. mocked handlers in my test suite)

The absence/existence of the policy handler is confirmed in both cases using debug inspection.

According to all documentation I've found on the subject, both options should be equivalent, at least in regards to the constructed `HttpClient` that I obtain in the end. But that is not the case here.

The documentation I find specifies that `HttpClient` can be injected when using **typed** clients:

- The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1), specifically the "typed clients" section example.
- This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280153/dependency-injection-httpclient-or-httpclientfactory)
- This [blog post](https://www.parksq.co.uk/dotnet-core/dependency-injection-httpclient-and-ihttpclientfactory)

I'm using a typed client but injecting a `HttpClient` clearly doesn't work for me.

Why does injecting a `HttpClient` vs injecting `IHttpClientFactory` work differently in my case?

Comment: Remove `services.AddSingleton<FooService>();` - You don't need that, and it's actually overwriting some of the configuration done by the `AddTypedClient` call that precedes it. I think that might be all you need to fix it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin **Winner winner, chicken dinner!** Post an answer and I'll accept + bounty it when I can. This does complicate things a bit, since that means that the consumers of my library aren't allowed to set up their own services. That's going to be annoying when they want to register `<FooService>`, `<IFooService, FooService>`, `<IEvenMoreBaseService, FooService>`, and the whole scoped/transient/singleton logic.

Comment: Does reversing the two lines (rather than removing one) work instead? _Just for interest's sake._

Comment: @mjwills: It does work, but the first line effectively gets ignored. Just tested it by setting a debug value and I noticed that after adding the typed client, any `FooService` dependency configuration I set up beforehand is no longer present, and the injected dependencies are "default" `FooService` instances with the correct httpclient injected. Overall, the DI framework's behavior feels more finicky than it should be, but at least it works now :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In effect, you have the following two registrations for your `FooService` class:

1. `services.AddHttpClient<FooService>()`
2. `services.AddSingleton<FooService>();`

Because of how the DI container works behind-the-scenes, the second registration overwrites the first. If you remove the second registration, the first will be used, and so your constructor with the `HttpClient` parameter will be invoked.

Comment: Just to slightly extend for future readers, by removing the `AddSingleton` line, the `HttpClient` approach is fixed, but the `IHttpClientFactory` approach breaks. You should call `AddSingleton` (and similar) only for those classes that rely on `IHttpClientFactory`.